# CakePHP - XML helper issue

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to spit out XML from an array.
So it almost work except that now I'm seeing this error "Resource interpreted as document but transferred with MIME type application/xml."

When I look at the source, what is being printed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    ...
</response>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

How do I get rid of that second

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Seems like that automatically gets added.

This is the url I have constructed /services/config.xml

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Your view template should be located in the xml subfolder

```
/app/views/services/xml/config.ctp
```

The xml tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` is then automatically rendered by the cake framework, so you should NOT have this tag in you config.ctp template. All you need to do is render your `<response></response>`.

Also, your services controller should render the content type HTTP header in the afterFilter:

```
function afterFilter()
{
    $this->header('Content-Type: application/xml'); 
}
```

Good luck!